# React Native, executing expensive task in background?

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

Messing around with react-native generating some pub/priv RSA keys:

As you can see below, I have a spinner that conditionally triggers based on the state variable. The problem is, the main UI thread is frozen before it can execute, even though the state has flipped. I almost attempted getting workers to work in the RN environment, but was a huge pain.

What are my options here? I want the loader to run after the button is clicked and during the computation, but to stop when the computation is finished.

I'd also like to remove that `activateLoader()` function.

### My Hack

```
activateLoader() {
    this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.visible);
        setInterval(() => {
            this.generateKeys();
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

### Class Example for Key Generation

```
class Controls extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            visible: false
        };
    }

    activateLoader() {
        this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.visible);
            this.generateKeys();
        });
    }

    generateKeys() {
        RSA.generateKeys(4096)
            .then(keys => {
                Toast.show(`Public & Private Keys Have Been\
                 Saved To Device and Encrypted`, Toast.LONG);

                this.setState({
                    visible: !this.state.visible
                });
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.parentViewStyle}>
                <Spinner visible={this.state.visible} textContent={"Generating Key Pairs"} textStyle={{ color: '#000' }} />
                <ControlButton
                    btnLabel="Join Encrypted Room"
                />
                <ControlButton
                    btnLabel="Generate Public/Private Key Pair"
                    onClick={() => this.activateLoader()}
                />
            </View >
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Potential solution from https://corbt.com/posts/2015/12/22/breaking-up-heavy-processing-in-react-native.html

```
import nextFrame from 'next-frame';

  async activateLoader() {
    this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
    await nextFrame();
    this.generateKeys();
}
```

> Every time await nextFrame() is called, the function’s execution will pause until the next render cycle starts. This allows the app to respond to user input and render animations before coming back to process the next item in our list.